# で終わります: trying to close by? で帰ります, trying to leave by? It depends on the sentence?

Tags: word-choice, nuances, particles, particle-で

I can say 売り場は九時で終わります、 and 三時で帰ります、 which I've learned mean something like, "They'll be trying to close from," and, "I'll be trying to leave from."  I've also learned that ２月２５日で帰ります is not correct.  What are the rules surrounding the use of で in the place of に・から?  Is there a more approximate meaning

Comment: @Flaw: 帰りくる is an old-fashioned synonym for 帰ってくる.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`で` here is used as a particle to mark a time where an event terminates.

`売り場は九時で終わります` is a correct use of this `で`. (The closing(termination) of the 売り場).

`三時で行きます` and　`２月２５日で行きます` is not correct because it's a start of something.

And for cases where `に` and `で` are interchangeable, the nuance is that the sentence with `で` indicates that the event lasts up to the point of the time marked by `で`. While the version with に just means it ends at that point.

About `~から`, it means "from the point of ~". It would be more natural to say "something ends at ~" than "something ends from ~ onwards". That's why `で` is used over `から` for an event terminating.

As a side note, "trying to ~" is expressed by `~ようとする`

**EDIT:**

In the absence of context, `三時で帰る` would mean "Return (home) by means of 3 O'clock", which doesn't make sense. This `で` is different from the first `で` we initially discussed. This is the `で` of　"the condition/state of how the action takes place".

`三時間で帰る` - "Return in 3 hours time (it takes 3 hours to travel back)" would make sense.

However, in the presence of context like "**ending** office hours", 三時で帰る is grammatical.

Similarly, `[２]{に}月{がつ}[２５]{にじゅうご}日{にち}で帰る` would be "Return (home) by means of 25th February", unless context of something ending is given.

`[２]{に}[ヶ]{か}月{げつ}２５日{にち}` - "Return in 2 months and 25 days (it takes 2 months 25 days to travel back)" would make sense.

Now if you're trying to convey a time limit, `までに` is used.

> ３時までに帰る　- "Return home by 3 O'clock"

---

**EDIT2:**

About 三月で私の国に帰ります. I'm not sure about this but I offer two theories:

> 1. It suffers the same limitation as the example discussed above. If sufficient context is given that something ends at 三月, then 三月で私の国に帰ります is grammatical. If not it becomes the で of means and sounds weird.
> 2. 三月 is not specific enough a time for で to be used as a marker for the time where something terminates. 三月 lasts from 一日 to 三十一日.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I meant to use the verb 帰ります.  I'll make the appropriate changes.

Comment: Any comment about the use of 帰ります with で?

Comment: 三時で帰る is grammatical when, say, the speaker is talking about when he/she leaves the office.

Comment: I agree, Ito, but I don't know why it's not okay to say 三月で私の国に帰ります。

Comment: @Flaw: I do not think that the combination “にから” is grammatical.  Also, the asker is not asking about that combination.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Oh I missed the ・ in に・から. It felt weird to me too but I went ahead assuming that it was grammatical and interpreted it according to how I understand に and から. And yes in the presence of context like "ending office hours", 三時で帰る is grammatical. I will edit to reflect the above issues in a moment.

Comment: I don't understand why people in all countries seem to assume that someone has made a mistake when they haven't heard context....  For example, I would hope someone wouldn't assume it was the  で of means if they hadn't heard the context.  My experiences makes me feel they might.  Perhaps I'm just wrong to feel suspicious, though.  But anyway, this is a great explanation. :D

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 I think it's different for each person. For me, I assume `で of means` because no other context is present, and it cannot be `で of location of verb action`. But it is also possible to logically eliminate `で of means` to get `で of termination`.(三時で, It is not a duration, it cannot be a means, it's not a location of verb action, by elimination I'm only left with...) It depends on which step of logic you decide to process first. Different people will have different "default" settings that we all fall back on.