# Using the で particle for time limits: ダイエットは３日で止めて仕舞った

Tags: meaning, particle-で

> ダイエットは３日で止めて仕舞った。

My loose translation would be

> I already gave up on the diet after 3 days.

And a more precise one

> As for the diet, I regrettably stopped it after 3 days.

From my understanding, で is used to say "after". But で usually marks the method by which an action occurs.

So, is my translation "after 3 days" correct?
Can you name a more precise translation for the example?
And what is the semantic of で in respect to this example?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/62192/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3410/9831

Comment: Does this answer your question? [で終わります: trying to close by? で帰ります, trying to leave by? It depends on the sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/%e3%81%a7%e7%b5%82%e3%82%8f%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%99-trying-to-close-by-%e3%81%a7%e5%b8%b0%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%99-trying-to-leave-by-it-depends-on-the-sentenc)

Answer (score 1):

Your translation sounds nice and correct. 仕舞った（しまった） sounds a regrettable nuance so the second one is also done well.

---

Other than marking the method, で may appear next to a duration when you do something in the (limited) duration.

> A: 夏休{なつやす}みの宿題{しゅくだい}を[3日]{みっか}で[終]{お}わらせたよ。」
> (I finished the homework of the summer holidays in 3 days.)
> B: [3日]{みっか}で！？
> (Only 3 days!?)

---

> A: [手伝]{てつだ}ってくれない？[5分]{ごふん}でいいから
> （Could you help me? It'll take only 5 minutes.）
> B: [忙]{いそが}しいけど[5分]{ごふん}ならいいよ。
> (I'm busy now but, okay, only 5 minutes.)

Comment: 終わらせた sounds wrong to me here.  Like "I made the homework finish (itself)".

Comment: I’m not sure if the で in the last dialog is the same. That 5分 could be replaced with something that is not a duration, such as 明日.

Comment: @istrasci - 終わらせた is correct. It works the same way as 済ませた. It’s kind of like saying “got it done” in that the verb takes what is finished as a direct object.